# Calling a unique random value within a .forEach() loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, foreach

I have a function that picks a random colour from an array of colours.

```js
const dynamicColors = () => {
  const colors = ['#FFC100', '#FF7400', '#FF0000', '#4BBDAD', '#0C1938', '#848483'];
  const randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  return randomColor;
};
```

I am then calling this function from within a `.forEach()` loop.

```js
traitInfo.forEach((t) => {
    const trait = {
      id: t.id,
      label: t.label,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: dynamicColors(),
      borderCapStyle: 'square',
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      pointHoverRadius: 8,
      pointRadius: 4,
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      data: [],
    };
    traitDatasets.push(trait);
  });
```

I am creating a Graph and using the above technique will, of course, render two or more colours that are the same within the graph which makes for a poor UX.

Desired output is to have `backgroundColor` display each of the colours in the array in turn. `traitInfo` will never have more than six values.

Comment: if I understand correctly you want to get a random value which was not used yet for this `forEach`

Comment: You could shuffle the array first if you want the colors different each time the graph is drawn, and then pick from the array in sequence instead of randomly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const randomly = () => Math.random() - 0.5;
const colors = ['#FFC100','#FF7400','#FF0000','#4BBDAD','#0C1938','#848483'];

const traitInfo = Array(6).fill({}); // for the snippet.
const dynamicColors = [].concat(colors).sort(randomly);

traitInfo.forEach((t, i) => {
  console.info(dynamicColors[i]);
});
```

Comment: Legend. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need? It shuffles colors and pick them by current forEach index.

```
// define colors somewhere
var colors - ['#FFC100', '#FF7400', '#FF0000', '#4BBDAD', '#0C1938', '#848483'];

// shuffle colors before pick and pick by 'colors[index]' of forEach
colors.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
traitInfo.forEach((t,index) => {
    const trait = {
      id: t.id,
      label: t.label,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: colors[index],
      borderCapStyle: 'square',
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      pointHoverRadius: 8,
      pointRadius: 4,
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      data: [],
    };
    traitDatasets.push(trait);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

using a closure to ensure I do not touch the original array

```js
let button = document.getElementById("button")

const dynamicColors = () => {
  const colors = ['#FFC100', '#FF7400', '#FF0000', '#4BBDAD', '#0C1938', '#848483'];
  return () => { // returns a function which returns a color
    const randomColor = colors.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length), 1);
    // splice ensure you can't get the same color twice since it removes from the array
    return randomColor[0];
  }
}

let divs = document.querySelectorAll("div")
button.onclick = () => {
  let getColor = dynamicColors()
  Array.from(divs).forEach(div => {
    div.style.backgroundColor = getColor()
  })
}
```

```html
<div id="p1">1</div>
<div id="p2">2</div>
<div id="p3">3</div>
<div id="p4">4</div>
<div id="p5">5</div>
<div id="p6">6</div>
<button id="button">colorize</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of shuffling, you may use a function generator to get the random element of the remaining elements, relying on its `next` element until `done` (the part checking whether it's `done` is not included), assuming you want a **unique value for each element in array**.

Sample working code:

```js
function* colorPicker(colors) {
  while (colors && colors.length) {
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    yield colors[index]; // <-- yields a random color.
    colors.splice(index, 1); // <-- removes the random color from the list.
  }
}

// Returns a Generator.
const cPicker = colorPicker(['#FFC100', '#FF7400', '#FF0000', '#4BBDAD', '#0C1938', '#848483']);

var test = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

// Sample usage:
test = test.map(i => ({i}));
test.forEach(trait => {
  trait.color = cPicker.next().value; // picks the next value of the generator.
});

console.log(test);
```

How you would use that in your code:

```
traitInfo.forEach((t) => {
    const trait = {
      id: t.id,
      label: t.label,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: cPicker.next().value, // <-- change here
      borderCapStyle: 'square',
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      pointHoverRadius: 8,
      pointRadius: 4,
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      data: [],
    };
    traitDatasets.push(trait);
  });
```

**side note** the function* code actually **splices** element from the array: you should make a copy of it if you want to use that and avoid losing colors, or just provide a copy of the array, the above code is just a sample of another possible approach, in my opinion a clever one.